# Does the Leibniz rule for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x,y\right)dy$ apply when $x$ is a function of $y$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, leibniz-integral-rule

Leibniz rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x,y\right)dy=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}dy$$

But what if $x$ is a function $y$? (Assume it's smooth and has any nice properties you want, but it isn't a constant.) Can I apply Leibniz rule and say

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\left(y\right),y\right)dy=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial f\left(x\left(y\right),y\right)}{\partial x}dy$$

Comment: If $x$ is a function of $y$, then the whole integral is a constant, and taking its (partial?) derivative in $x$ does not make much sense to begin with.

Comment: To answer plainly, and going off of @G.Sassatelli’s comment: I believe yes.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor, https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/14068/regarding-a-consumption-aggregator-how-do-i-differentiate-under-the-integral-si